# Optimizing a query, not sure where to start. Written by someone else

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All of the Left outer joins can't be good.  The execution plan on the batch says this query cost 81% of the overall batch.  Is there any other way to write the left outer joins without so much query cost!  They are performing much of the same code only against different columns.

```
insert into #temptable
select rp.security_id, rp.rating_date, 
   ml_new.rating, mcps_new.rating, ms_new.rating, 
   sl_new.rating, scps_new.rating, ss_new.rating, 
   fl_new.rating, fs_new.rating,
   case when ml_new.security_id is null then null else ml_old.rating end,
   case when mcps_new.security_id is null then null else mcps_old.rating end,
   case when ms_new.security_id is null then null else ms_old.rating end,
   case when sl_new.security_id is null then null else sl_old.rating end,
   case when scps_new.security_id is null then null else scps_old.rating end,
   case when ss_new.security_id is null then null else ss_old.rating end,
   case when fl_new.security_id is null then null else fl_old.rating end,
   case when fs_new.security_id is null then null else fs_old.rating end,
   ml_new.rating_score, mcps_new.rating_score, ms_new.rating_score, 
   sl_new.rating_score, scps_new.rating_score, ss_new.rating_score, 
   fl_new.rating_score, fs_new.rating_score,
   ml_old.rating_score, mcps_old.rating_score, ms_old.rating_score,
   sl_old.rating_score, scps_old.rating_score, ss_old.rating_score,
   fl_old.rating_score, fs_old.rating_score
from #rating_pop rp
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ml_new on ml_new.security_id = rp.security_id and ml_new.agency_code = 'MOODY_L' and ml_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings mcps_new on mcps_new.security_id = rp.security_id and mcps_new.agency_code = 'MOODY_CP_S' and mcps_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ms_new on ms_new.security_id = rp.security_id and ms_new.agency_code = 'MOODY_S' and ms_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings sl_new on sl_new.security_id = rp.security_id and sl_new.agency_code = 'SP_L' and sl_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings scps_new on scps_new.security_id = rp.security_id and scps_new.agency_code = 'SP_CP_S' and scps_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ss_new on ss_new.security_id = rp.security_id and ss_new.agency_code = 'SP_S' and ss_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fl_new on fl_new.security_id = rp.security_id and fl_new.agency_code = 'FITCH_L' and fl_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fs_new on fs_new.security_id = rp.security_id and fs_new.agency_code = 'FITCH_S' and fs_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ml_old on ml_old.security_id = rp.security_id and ml_old.agency_code = 'MOODY_L' and ml_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ml_old2 where ml_old2.security_id = ml_old.security_id and ml_old2.agency_code = ml_old.agency_code and ml_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings mcps_old on mcps_old.security_id = rp.security_id and mcps_old.agency_code = 'MOODY_CP_S' and mcps_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings mcps_old2 where mcps_old2.security_id = mcps_old.security_id and mcps_old2.agency_code = mcps_old.agency_code and mcps_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ms_old on ms_old.security_id = rp.security_id and ms_old.agency_code = 'MOODY_S' and ms_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ms_old2 where ms_old2.security_id = ms_old.security_id and ms_old2.agency_code = ms_old.agency_code and ms_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings sl_old on sl_old.security_id = rp.security_id and sl_old.agency_code = 'SP_L' and sl_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings sl_old2 where sl_old2.security_id = sl_old.security_id and sl_old2.agency_code = sl_old.agency_code and sl_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings scps_old on scps_old.security_id = rp.security_id and scps_old.agency_code = 'SP_CP_S' and scps_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings scps_old2 where scps_old2.security_id = scps_old.security_id and scps_old2.agency_code = scps_old.agency_code and scps_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ss_old on ss_old.security_id = rp.security_id and ss_old.agency_code = 'SP_S' and ss_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings ss_old2 where ss_old2.security_id = ss_old.security_id and ss_old2.agency_code = ss_old.agency_code and ss_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fl_old on fl_old.security_id = rp.security_id and fl_old.agency_code = 'FITCH_L' and fl_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fl_old2 where fl_old2.security_id = fl_old.security_id and fl_old2.agency_code = fl_old.agency_code and fl_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
left outer join datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fs_old on fs_old.security_id = rp.security_id and fs_old.agency_code = 'FITCH_S' and fs_old.rating_date = (select max(rating_date) from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings fs_old2 where fs_old2.security_id = fs_old.security_id and fs_old2.agency_code = fs_old.agency_code and fs_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
```

Comment: You could try doing 1 left join, and using a CASE WHEN expression for each column, but then you would have to group and so on, not sure it would make it any better.

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server is this for?

Comment: It's against a 2005 instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this as an aggregation query with conditional aggregation.  This is a very complex query, but here is how you would get started:

```
select rp.security_id, rp.rating_date,
       max(case when agency_code = 'MOODY_L' then rating end) as MOODY_L,
       max(case when agency_code = 'MOODY_CP_S' then rating end) as MOODY_CP_S,
       max(case when agency_code = 'MOODY_S' then rating end) as MOODY_S,
       . . .
from #rating_pop rp
group by rp.security_id, rp.rating_date;
```

You have more complicated logic in there to choose other dates.  I don't understand the layout of the data enough to know exactly what to do.  I suspect that using `row_number()` might fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a projection and do a pivot on fctSecurityRatings . This would allow one join into the pivot.

May be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the kind of thing you'll have to do several iterations on. I would start by doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
    rp.security_id, 
    rp.rating_date, 
    CASE WHEN rating_new.agency_code = 'MOODY_L' THEN rating_new.rating ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN rating_new.security_id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE rating_old.rating END,
    CASE WHEN rating_new.agency_code = 'MOODY_L' THEN rating_new.rating_score ELSE NULL END,
FROM #rating_pop AS rp
    LEFT JOIN datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings AS rating_new
        ON rating_new.security_id = rp.security_id 
        AND rating_new.rating_date = rp.rating_date
    LEFT JOIN datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings AS rating_old
        ON rating_old.security_id = rp.security_id 
        AND rating_old.rating_date = 
            (select max(rating_date) 
            from datamart.dbo.fctSecurityRatings rating_old2 
            where rating_old2.security_id = rating_old.security_id 
                and rating_old2.agency_code = rating_old.agency_code 
                and rating_old2.rating_date < rp.rating_date)
```

(`CASE` statements for each of the other `agency_code`s would needed as well.) That should produce the same result without doing several dozen `JOIN`s to the same table. If you have the option though I'd suggest reworking the query so that it outputs the columns `agency_code`, `rating`, and `rating_score`, one `agency_code` per row, and then transform the data to be horizontal instead of vertical (either with a `PIVOT` or in code.)